# How to provide relative path for log files in Node forever

Tags: node.js, logging, forever

I am using forever to start a node.js application using  the following command:

`forever start -l /<fullpath to my folder>/logs/forever_log.log -a server.js`

If I run it as:

`forever start -l forever_log.log -a server.js`

Then it is correctly creating the logs in the current directory

My goal is to write the logs into a sub directory within the current directory, so I have tried the following:

`forever start -l logs/forever_log.log -a server.js`

`forever start -l /logs/forever_log.log -a server.js`

`forever start -l ./logs/forever_log.log -a server.js`

`forever start -l logs/forever_log.log -a server.js --workingDir .`

None of it seems to be working

**What is the correct syntax for specifying a relative path so that forever writes the logs into a subfolder called "logs" inside my current working directory** from which I am calling forever start